# Angular/Fire: How to get detail from multiple collection in firebase first call id dependent on second call

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire

I'm using real-time database from firebase and using `@angular/fire`. I stored all reservation details under `reservation` collection (see example in reservation response). I wanted to all get client detail from from `client` collection by passing clientId in `getClientDetails`. I'm getting the list of events and client when `console.log`. But this I can't get it in `app.component.ts`. Please let me know if I missed anything

**app.service.ts**

```
export class ReservationsService {
 constructor(
    private angularFireDB: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {}

   getClientDetails(clientId: string) {
    console.log('getClientDetails called with clientId:', clientId);
    return this.angularFireDB
      .object(`clients/${clientId}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        tap(client => console.log('Client data:', client))
      );
  }

getDocumentByEventId(eventId: string) {
    console.log('getDocumentByEventId called with eventId:', eventId);
    return this.angularFireDB
      .list('reservation', (ref) =>
        ref.orderByChild('eventId').equalTo(eventId)
      )
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        tap(documents => console.log('Documents:', documents)),
        switchMap((documents: any[]) =>
          documents.length > 0
            ? forkJoin(
                documents.map(document => 
                  this.getClientDetails(document.clientId).pipe(
                    map(clientDetails => ({ ...document, clientDetails }))
                  )
                )
              )
            : of([]) // return an Observable of empty array if no documents
        )
      );
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventId = this.route.snapshot.params['eventId'];

    this.reservationService.getDocumentByEventId(this.eventId)
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log('Data from getDocumentByEventId:', data),
      error => console.error('Error:', error)
    );


  }
```

reservation response:

```
[
    {
        "category": "",
        "clientId": "100",
        "eventId": "-NWsm0EeULzec2XhkO36",
        "regularTicketTotal": 66,
        "regularTickets": 2,
        "studentTicketTotal": 108,
        "studentTickets": 4
    },
    {
        "category": "",
        "clientId": "101",
        "eventId": "-NWsm0EeULzec2XhkO36",
        "regularTicketTotal": 99,
        "regularTickets": 3,
        "studentTicketTotal": 108,
        "studentTickets": 4
    }
]
```